# NLP searching to generate reports?

Tags: search, neo4j, nlp, stanford-nlp, data-mining

Apologies for what will be a relatively open ended question but I am stuck on where to begin to read, test and start playing around with creating a NLP search that eventually leads to a visual graph from data in a graph database.

Example:  https://gist.github.com/ikwattro/071d36f135131e8e4442

In that graph database above they outlined a few questions and showed the neo4j queries for them.  How would I go about building out a NLP if I wanted to build a test system that answers those questions.

Question examples:

1. Which repository has been the most forked?
2. How many forks are resulting in an opened pr?
3. Who did the most events?

This is similar to a system that thoughtspot.com and answerocket.com have.

Comment: So you have a graph and you want to answer questions with the information in the graph?